# How to check if at least one option button in an option button group is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have option button groups on a userform and need to validate that at least one option button in each group has been clicked. Is there any way of doing this without examining each button's value individually? Can an option button group as a whole be referenced?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But there is a dirty alternative (in case you do not want to loop). Let's say you have 3 groups; Then declare 3 public variables. In the click event of the option button, set the variables to True. Now simply check if the 3 variables are true or not :)

Comment: Let me know if you want an example?

Comment: No that's fine, I get it. The only problem is if you have loads of option buttons it will be a bit of a pain to add the code for each button's click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to set a default value at load time for each group.  That way no looping, no extra public variables, and no reason to verify that an option button in the group has been ticked.

Edited to show example (I also acknowledge that it's also a clunky hack):

If you're not opposed to using a range of cells to hold values, you can use the option button's "ContolSource" property and set it to a cell.  Something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Sheet1.Range("A:B").Delete
' Group 1
    OptionButton1.ControlSource = "Sheet1!A1"
    OptionButton2.ControlSource = "Sheet1!A2"
' Group 2
    OptionButton3.ControlSource = "Sheet1!B1"
    OptionButton4.ControlSource = "Sheet1!B2"
End Sub
```

Now you can count the # of cells that have a value in each column. If a column has at least 1 value, then you know an option button has been ticked for that group

Comment: Thanks yes I thought about that, but I really want the user to actively make a selection.

Comment: @aardvark123 I edited my answer to give another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best solution to handle the situation dynamically.